# Sendkeys not sending keys consistently WebDriverAgent (iOS-XCUITest)

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am automating an iOS application. Please find the versions of the applications:

> Appium CLI: 1.9.1 
>  WebDriverAgent: The same that came with Appium
>   CLI. 
>  MacOS: 10.14.1 
>  iOS version: 10.3.3 
>  Device: iPad
>   
>  Driver: XCUITest (WebDriverAgent)

Problem experiencing:

When I am using `element.sendkeys("Prakash")`, it's either entering **"rakash"** or **"Prkash"** or **"Praksh"**. It's never consistent. It's happening for all the fields.

I have reinstalled webdriveragent multiple times, but has not helped.

Is anybody aware of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Please find the logs from iOS real device:

> ```
> 2018-11-27 15:57:03:266 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/element/1E000000-0000-0000-B00A-000000000000/value' to command name
> ```
>
> 'setValue'
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:266 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element/1E000000-0000-0000-B00A-000000000000/value] to [POST
>   http://localhost:8100/session/0DFDAB38-2909-4D3C-AB87-F5493252D239/element/1E000000-0000-0000-B00A-000000000000/value] with body: {"value":["x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","1","2","3"]}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:279 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:279 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:280 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:280 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:280 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:280 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:280 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:281 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO testmanagerd[2729] : 
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:281 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:282 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:283 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:284 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:285 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:285 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:286 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:287 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:287 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:288 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:289 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:289 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:290 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:290 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:291 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}
>       2018-11-27 15:57:03:291 - [iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Nov 27 23:57:03 GTO salesApp(UIAccessibility)[2736] : This child can't
>   be serialized correctly:  {pid=2736}

Comment: I also had a similar problem, while trying to send "Info2017Tmt" using sendkey() in  appium, it will sometime pass " Information about the Tmt" and somtimes it will pass the correct text. Don't know the exact reason. I was getting the text from the Excel file to pass to the app using sendkey(). The console will print the exact text from excel file. There may be some issue with sendkey() method.

Comment: There is a specific capability for XCUITest, i.e., `maxTypingFrequency`. This is defaulted to 60. I had to bring it down to 3/4 per min for it to work in my iOS application. That is a kill of time.

Comment: did you find a solution? this problem still exists with `Appium v2.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

```
desired_caps = {
                "platformName": "iOS",
                "platformVersion": "16.4",
                "deviceName": "iPhone 14",
                "automationName": "XCUITest",
                "bundleId": "",
                "udid": "",
                "maxTypingFrequency": 30
}
```

Adding `maxTypingFrequency` solve it, the default is 60 so try slowing it down, the safest in my case is 30, but try to adjust it base on your simulators performance.

Comment: I love you.  Just let me know where to send the check $

Answer (score 0):

First perform click on textField then perform sendkeys, this should work.
If the issue still exists and If you are performing very important operation, convert string to char and do sendkeys. Below is the code.

```
public void stringToChar(WebElement element, String value){
        String val = value;
        element.click();
        element.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++){
            char c = val.charAt(i);
            String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
            element.sendKeys(s);
        } 
        
     }
```